# Rails 3.2, How to refresh current URL locale when changing locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have my url looks like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/en/experiments
```

when I change the locale, all strings get translated fine, 
but, the url locale do not change to

`http://0.0.0.0:3000/ar/experiments` , unless I press any link, it will be refreshed

here is my routes.rb:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|ar/ do
    resources :experiments
    resources :users
    resources :class_rooms
  end

match 'lang' => 'home#set_lang'
```

here is the home controller:

```
def set_lang
    I18n.locale = params[:id]
    redirect_to :back
end
```

links at view:

```
= link_to "Arabic", :controller => 'home', :action => 'set_lang', :id => 'ar'
= link_to "English", :controller => 'home', :action => 'set_lang', :id => 'en'
```

so, how can I refresh the url to reflect the new locale, 
shouldn't `redirect_to :back` do so ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 2 years old, but hey. I had the exact same problems and I solved it.

Provided that you have included this in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
   {locale: I18n.locale}.merge options
end
```

You don't need any controller or actions. Instead, just do this:

```
= link_to 'Arabic', locale: :ar
= link_to 'English', locale: :en
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like [routing-filter](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter) instead of a custom solution to this problem. Additionally, calling the parameter "id" seems *weird*. A better name for it would be "locale", no?

Comment: Thanks, I will check the routing-filter, yes, its better to use locale as a parameter name :-)

Comment: routing-filter didn't solve the problem, I need a way to refresh the url local right after I chose a different locale, currently, url local changed only when I set a new local + visit a different link ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your application controller?

```
# pass in language as a default url parameter
def default_url_options(options = {})
   {locale: I18n.locale}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can't because you are redirecting to :back which is the url with the old locale.

```
def set_lang
    I18n.locale = params[:id]
    redirect_to :back
end
```

One way to change the locale and keep the current URL is to do something like this

```
 - I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
   = link_to t(locale, :scope => [:languages]), params.merge(:locale => locale), :id => locale, :title => t(locale, :scope => [:languages]), :alt => t(locale, :scope => [:languages])
```